# Python Datetime offset

Tags: python, django, date, utc, gmt

Do the terms "GMT offset" and "UTC offset" refer to the same "offset"?

I.e. if I have a Python/Django timezone-aware datetime called `mydt`, and I print it this way:

```
In [1]: mydt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
Out[1]: '2013-07-20T23:50:00+0200'
```

Is the *UTC* offset returned for `%z` in the form +HHMM or -HHMM the same as a *GMT* offset for the same date? In my case it is `+0200`.

I tried googling, but what I've found is the history of GMT and why UTC was needed later on. Although things look like GMT and UTC are the same, I need to be 100% sure.

Comment: From developer point of view they are the same although geographer would probably argue they aren't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UTC = GMT +/- 0.9s,
so they are almost the same